# Linked List output

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, allocation

I'm doing a school assignment and I've only started on C programming a few months back. In this assignment, I'm to output the space occupied by a 'file'.

The initial output is correct, however, when i try to print out a table, the output becomes incorrect.

Codes:

```
#define TOTAL_DISK_BLOCKS 32
#define TOTAL_DISK_INODES 8
int blockStatus[TOTAL_DISK_BLOCKS];                   // free = 0
int blockList[TOTAL_DISK_BLOCKS - TOTAL_DISK_INODES]; // list of blocks of a file
struct file_table
{
    char fileName[20];
    int fileSize;
    struct block *sb; // start block
};
struct file_table fileTable[TOTAL_DISK_BLOCKS - TOTAL_DISK_INODES];

struct block
{
    int blockNumber;
    struct block *next;
} * head;
int AllocateBlocks(int Size)
{
    int i = 0, count = 0, inList = 0, nextBlock = 0, j = 0, dcount = 0, fails = 0;
    int allocStartBlock = TOTAL_DISK_INODES;
    int allocEndBlock = TOTAL_DISK_BLOCKS - 1;
    // check whether sufficient free blocks are available
    // some codes here     
    {

        for (j = 0; j < Size; j++)
        {
            nextBlock = (rand() % (allocEndBlock - allocStartBlock + 1)) + allocStartBlock;

            if (blockStatus[nextBlock] == 0)
            {
                // printf("\ncount:%d\n", count);
                blockList[j] = nextBlock;
                count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
                fails += 1;
                // printf("\nfails:%d, block %d taken\n", fails, nextBlock);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // remaining blocks left
    dcount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (TOTAL_DISK_BLOCKS - TOTAL_DISK_INODES); i++)
        if (blockStatus[i] == 0)
            dcount++;
    printf("Remaining blocks: %d\n", dcount);
    if (count == Size)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Size; j++)
        {
            blockStatus[blockList[j]] = 1;
        }
        return 0; // success
    }

    else
        return 1; // not successful
}

void printBlockNumbers(struct block *temp)
{

    // Return if list is empty
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.");
        return;
    }

    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("-%d", temp->blockNumber); // Print data of current node
        temp = temp->next;                // Move to next node
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, numFiles = 0, nextBlock = 0, ret = 1;
    char s[20];
    struct block *temp, *newBlock;

    //some print codes here...

    scanf("%d", &numFiles);

    for (i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the name of file #%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", fileTable[i].fileName);
        printf("Enter the size (kB) of file #%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &fileTable[i].fileSize);
        ret = AllocateBlocks(fileTable[i].fileSize);
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            head = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
            head->blockNumber = blockList[0];
            head->next = NULL;
            temp = head;

            for (j = 1; j < fileTable[i].fileSize; j++)
            {
                newBlock = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));

                newBlock->blockNumber = blockList[j]; // Link data field of newNode
                newBlock->next = NULL;                // Make sure new node points to NULL

                temp->next = newBlock; // Link previous node with newNode
                temp = temp->next;     // Make current node as previous node
            }
            printf("Blocks occupied");
            printBlockNumbers(fileTable[i].sb);
            printf("\nFile allocation success\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nFile allocation failed\n");
        }
    }
    // Seed the pseudo-random number generator used by rand() with the value seed

    srand(1234);
    printf("\nFile Allocation Table\n");
    printf("%s%20s%40s\n", "FILE_NAME", "FILE_SIZE", "BLOCKS_OCCUPIED");

    for (i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
    {

        printf("%s%20d", fileTable[i].fileName, fileTable[i].fileSize);
        printf("\t\t\t\t");
        printBlockNumbers(fileTable[i].sb);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("File allocation completed. Exiting.\n");
}
```

Below is the first output.

```
Blocks occupied-15-30-17

Blocks occupied-21-10-27-10

Blocks occupied-20-26-12-24-19
```

And this is the table output.

```
File Allocation Table
FILE_NAME           FILE_SIZE                         BLOCKS_OCCUPIED
3                   3                           -20-26-12-24-19
4                   4                           -20-26-12-24-19
5                   5                           -20-26-12-24-19
File allocation completed. Exiting.
```

Comment: that's a long code :) however at first glimpse you're passing pointer as a value to printBlockNumbers and then reassign local (copied) variable in this function to value of global variable 'head', so this function does the same thing every time it is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first loop you're printing newly allocated list each time, but in second loop you're printing last allocated list as you're printing from list which tail is a global variable `head`.

in here:

```
void printBlockNumbers(struct block *temp)
{

    // Return if list is empty
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.");
        return;
    }

    temp = head;
```

initial value of temp does not matter.

here:

```
head = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
head->blockNumber = blockList[0];
head->next = NULL;
temp = head;
```

you're assigning `temp` value of `head`, so `temp->smth` points to the same address as `head->smth` so when you use `printBlockNumbers` to print `head` it will print out what was assigned to it in this loop.

you should change `printBlockNumbers` to that:

```
void printBlockNumbers(struct block *temp)
{
   // Return if list is empty
   if(!temp) {
      return;
   }
   
   while (temp != NULL)
   {
       printf("-%d", temp->blockNumber); // Print data of current node
       temp = temp->next;                // Move to next node
   }
```

and also assign `fileTable[i].sb` value of `head` in each loop and then free these lists at the end.

FYI:
if you'd like to pass something to function as a "referece" (i.e. pointer) to be able to change original value in this function you do this like that:

```
void changeIntToFive(int* a) {
   *a = 5;
}

int main(){
   int var = 1;
   changeIntToFive(&var);
   printf("%d\n", var);    // prints 5
}
```

and if you'd like to do the same to a pointer:

```
int glob = 5;

void makePtrPointToGlob(int** a) {
   *a = &glob;
}

int main(){
   int *ptr;
   makePtrPointToGlob(&ptr);
   printf("%d\n", *ptr);    // prints 5
}
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate you taking the time to look at my problem :) I see my mistake now! Pointers have been a really difficult subject for me, so I do need more practice on it

Comment: no problem :) you could mark my response as an answer though :)